# Displaying Windows Active Directory thumbnailPhoto in asp:net Search App

Tags: asp.net, gridview, active-directory

I've set up a WebApplication to search the Active Directory of our organization. The Query (dynamic SQL wrapping OpenQuery) returns also the hexadecimal data for the thumpnailPhoto.

When I'm displaying the image I get a 40% success on all pictures displayed. The "bad" ones are usually fine in the first 15% starting from the top and then stop with black stripes. Sometimes there is picture data repeated in stripes... Some profile pictures are not displayed at all, while others are perfect. There must be different image formats, but not having access to the storage positions of these images I do not get any further.

This is what I do:
I bind the data from the query to a GridView.

```
protected void FillGrid(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXXXXXXX");
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(@"declare @SQL nvarchar(4000)
                                             declare @Asterisc nvarchar(1)
                                             declare @Sub nvarchar(12)
                                             set @SearchName = CASE WHEN @SearchName = '' THEN '*' ELSE @SearchName END
                                             set @SearchSurename = CASE WHEN @SearchSurename = '' THEN '*' ELSE @SearchSurename END
                                             set @Asterisc = '*'
                                             set @Sub = CASE WHEN @Subsidiary = '*' THEN '' ELSE (@Subsidiary+', OU=') END
                                             set @SQL ='SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT samAccountName AS UserAccount, givenName AS FirstName, sn AS LastName, department, title AS Position, 
                                                               physicaldeliveryofficename AS Office, extensionAttribute1 AS PersonnelID, initials, mail AS email, telephonenumber AS Phone, extensionattribute5 AS Extension, 
                                                               mobile, extensionattribute3 AS MobileExt, thumbnailPhoto
                                                        FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, ''SELECT samAccountName, givenName, sn, legacyExchangeDN, department, title, physicaldeliveryofficename, extensionAttribute1, distinguishedName, initials,
                                                                                      mail, telephonenumber, extensionattribute5, mobile, extensionattribute3, thumbnailPhoto
                                                                               FROM ''''LDAP://OU=' + @Sub + 'XXXX, DC=XXXX,DC=XXXX,DC=XXXX''''
                                                                               WHERE objectClass=''''Person'''' AND objectClass = ''''User'''' AND givenName = ''''' + @SearchName + ''''' AND samAccountName = ''''' + @SearchSurename + ''''' AND extensionAttribute1 = ''''' + @Asterisc + ''''' '') AS AD_Users
                                                        ORDER BY UserAccount'
                                                        exec (@SQL)", objConn);
    objCommand.Parameters.Add("@SearchName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBoxSearchName.Text;
    objCommand.Parameters.Add("@SearchSurename", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBoxSearchSureName.Text;
    objCommand.Parameters.Add("@Subsidiary", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DDSubsidiary.Text;
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    adapter.SelectCommand = objCommand;
    objConn.Open();
    adapter.Fill(t);
    objConn.Close();
    GridView.DataSource = t;
    GridView.DataBind();
}
```

Then during the RowDataBound event I encode the data like this and bind that data to an asp:image control:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr["thumbnailPhoto"])))
        {
            string imageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])dr["thumbnailPhoto"]);
            (e.Row.FindControl("Image1") as Image).ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

What problem am I facing here and how to deal with it?

I just discovered that those pictures that are displayed partially or with stripes are all pictures that are stored in a bigger 600x600 format, while the good ones have a 96x96 format. That leads me to my suspicion that something is going wrong when retrieving the thumbprintPhoto in it's hexacecimal format through SQL.

As Gabriel suggested, I tried to use the DirectorySearcher. The thumbprintPhoto was displayed correctly but it took me more than 10 seconds to retrieve 44 AD entries: Here is my code

```
    protected void SearchAD(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = TextBoxSearchFirstName.Text;
        Name = Name.Replace("*", "") + "*";
        DirectorySearcher dsSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        dsSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user) (sn=" + Name + "))";
        results = dsSearcher.FindAll();

        DataTable t = new DataTable("ActiveDir");
        t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SecondName", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstName", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserID", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("data", System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]")));           

        if (results != null)
        {
            foreach (SearchResult searchResult in results)
            {
                DataRow myRow;
                myRow = t.NewRow();
                myRow[0] = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sn"].Value;
                myRow[1] = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenName"].Value;
                myRow[2] = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samAccountName"].Value;
                myRow[3] = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Value;
                t.Rows.Add(myRow);
            }
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = t;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Solved: Gabriel tuned the AD Search code and now it's faster than the SQL Query.
In order to display the AD Thumnail Profil pictures without using a handler do the decoding during the GridViews OnRowDataBound Event:

```
    protected void OnRowDataBoundAdUser(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dr["data"])))
            {
                byte[] data = dr["data"] as byte[];
                MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(data);
                byte[] imageBytes = s.ToArray();
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                string imageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
                (e.Row.FindControl("Image1") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image).ImageUrl = imageUrl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are going through SQL instead of using `DirectorySearcher`?

Comment: Is not knowing a good enough reason? I didn't know about the DirectorySearcher; now I tried it and retrieving the thumbnailPhoto actually works now for all pictures. But the method through SQL is much faster (immediate response vs. 10 seconds for 44 rows - without picture). The conversions (data->byte->Base64String) are the same in both approaches, so I guess something is happening with the raw data retrieved through SQL.

Comment: That's as good a reason as any :) `DirectorySearcher` should be faster since you're doing directly to AD rather than through an SQL server to AD. I'd have to see your code to comment though.

Comment: It's possible SQL is caching results. Try changing your criteria each time and see if you get different timings.

Comment: Gabriel, I just posted my code. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see why it's taking so long. `DirectorySearcher` and `DirectoryEntry` can be a little sneaky with how many times it reaches out to AD. You have a lot more network requests going on there than you need.

In your code, you're going out to AD once for the search. Then for each result, you're using `GetDirectoryEntry()`. Then `DirectoryEntry` is going out to AD again the first time you use `Properties`. Worse still, as soon as you use `Properties`, it downloads *every single attribute* that has a value, even though you're only actually using 4 of them. That's a whole lot of useless network traffic.

You can avoid this by using `Properties` collection in the search results, which already has all the attributes (by default it gets every attribute that has a value).

But you can do even better: If you set the `PropertiesToLoad` property of `DirectorySearcher` then it will only return the values you want to use. This way, you have one network request for everything you want, and *only* what you want.

```
protected void SearchAD(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Name = TextBoxSearchFirstName.Text;
    Name = Name.Replace("*", "") + "*";
    var dsSearcher = new DirectorySearcher {
        Filter = "(&(objectClass=user) (sn=" + Name + "))"
    };
    dsSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
    dsSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");
    dsSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName");
    dsSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("thumbnailPhoto");

    using (var results = dsSearcher.FindAll()) {
        var t = new DataTable("ActiveDir");
        t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SecondName", typeof(string)));
        t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstName", typeof(string)));
        t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserID", typeof(string)));
        t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("data", typeof(byte[])));

        foreach (SearchResult searchResult in results) {
            var myRow = t.NewRow();
            myRow[0] = searchResult.Properties.Contains("sn") ? searchResult.Properties["sn"][0] : null;
            myRow[1] = searchResult.Properties.Contains("givenName") ? searchResult.Properties["givenName"][0] : null;
            myRow[2] = searchResult.Properties.Contains("samAccountName") ? searchResult.Properties["samAccountName"][0] : null;
            myRow[3] = searchResult.Properties.Contains("thumbnailPhoto") ? searchResult.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0] : null;
            t.Rows.Add(myRow);
        }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = t;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

A few notes:

The calls to `Contains` are needed because if the attribute is empty, then it doesn't exist in the `Properties` collection at all.

The search results returns everything as an array, regardless of whether it is or not in AD. Thus, the `[0]` is needed for every attribute.

You'll notice I put a `using` statement around the search results. This is needed to prevent memory leaks, [according to the documentation of `FindAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall?view=netframework-4.7.1#remarks).